# Java Post Fix Expression

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, postfix-operator

I wrote a post-fix calculator:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class req1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Double result = 0D;
        String  input  ="";
        int count =1;

        while (count ==1) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Welcome to your Postfix Calculator\n====================\n");
            System.out.println("Enter your postfix expression, OR to exit type stop:");
            input = scan.nextLine();


            if (input.toLowerCase().equals("stop"))
            {
                System.out.println("Received stop command...");
                System.exit(0);
            }//end of if statement

            else{
                try
                {
                    String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
                    if (inputArray.length == 3)
                    {

                        Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
                        Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
                        String operator = inputArray[2];


                        switch (operator)
                        {
                            case "+":
                                result = number1 + number2;
                                break;
                            case "-":
                                result = number1 - number2;
                                break;
                            case "/":
                                result = number1 / number2;
                                break;
                            case "*":
                                result = number1 * number2;
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Received unsupported operator: " + operator);
                                break;
                        }//end of switch

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("invalid expression");
                    }}
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Error:\n" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not saying that this code doesn't work because it does, but it only works if the user enters the postfix expression as:

```
7 8 +
```

if the user enters like this:

```
7 + 8
```

the calculator doesn't come up with the error (`Invalid expression`), I don't know where it is I'm going wrong or if I'm missing something within my code. Also, when the result comes up it only comes up with the answer I need to make it work so that it comes up with the expression and then the answer

e.g.

> 7 8 +  
>  or 
>  7 + 8 
>  your result is: 7 + 8 = 15

Answer (score 0):

You have stored the order as number1, number2 and operator. So it is taing whatever the 3rd values of the array as operator.

```
Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
          Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
          String operator = inputArray[2];
```

If you want the correct order 7 + 8 then you need to store the oprator value as the inputArray[1] like this,

```
Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
          String operator = inputArray[1];
          Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[2]);
```

Then 7 + 8 will work correctly.

Comment: Thankyou for your help but I need it work so that when the user enters 7 + 8 it comes up with an error saying "invalid expression" and then it asks them again to enter there expression

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to add continue statement in the else block like this,

```
}else{
            System.out.println("invalid expression");
            continue;
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calculator, you get `Invalid expression` output, when there is more than 3 elements of expression, so with input like: `4 5 6 +`. Meanwhile, the input `1 + 3` couse the `NumberFormatException`, and it this case the `try{}catch{}` block do what you coded, so it only print error message.

If you want the input like `3 + 5` to give `Invalid expression`, add it to `try{}catch{}`, like:

```
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    System.err.println("Error:\n" + e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("invalid expression");
}
```

If you want a output in form `your result is: 7 + 8 = 15`, you can for example, first add declaration of both `Double` objects on beginning of `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double number1 = 0.0;
    Double number2 = 0.0;
```

so it would be accesible in whole method, and then modify the output line to:

```
System.out.println("Your result is" + number1 +" + "+ number2 + " = " + result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i've tried the invalid expression in the code but it still doesn't work. If the user enters 7 + 8 it says error input "+" string is wrong but i need it to say invalid 'expression

Comment: @computing the `System.err.println("Error:\n" + e.getMessage());` line gives you output: `Error: For input string: "+"`. If you don't want it, remove it, replece with `System.out.println("invalid expression");`

Comment: Also, add a `continue;` line after `System.out.println("invalid expression");` in `try{}catch` block, then it will not print the result line after exception.